# What is a Starcraft 2 "season"?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the SC2 online help, it's mentioned that leagues are played in seasons, and "the ladders will be wiped, allowing everyone to have a fresh start and begin anew."

Are there any details on this? How often will this occur? Will everyone have to be placed into leagues again?

Comment: Could you link the page?

Comment: @Doug, this is mentioned inside the game itself (in the online help). I don't think there's any way to link to it.

Comment: I'm curious if anymore information has been released about the length of a season.

Comment: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2267489003 is a good start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Season" in this case, refers to the same thing as a "Baseball Season" or "Football Season". Blizzard does this on most (all?) Battle.net games including Warcraft 3 and Diablo II.

"Wipe the ladders" is quite literal -- everyone, from the 'leetest' of the 'leet' to the worst of the worst gets a rating reset and must partake in their placement matches again. (But hey, at least that's another chance at the Hot Shot feat of strength!)

Comment: You know how often? Every year? 6 months? 3 months?

Comment: It will vary (if the length of WoW's Arena Seasons are any indication).

Comment: If they keep to an annual schedule with the SC2 trilogy, that would probably be an opportune time to reset the ladders. Everyone would get to qualify with new units, maps, etc.

Comment: I believe its only your ranking that gets reset, not your rating. Your rating (known as MMR) is used, alongside the placement match to decide which ladder you will be put into for the following season